# fails with firestore example in github of list

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, this

hello I hope you can help me my problem is that I am making some basic lists with the example that they give me in the github repository called angularfire and I get the following error:

```
Type 'Observable<DocumentData[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'.
```

Type 'DocumentData[]' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'.
Property 'name' is missing in type 'DocumentData' but required in type 'Item'

i pass my html, ts, module.ts:

archive html :

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of item$ | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

archive ts:

```
   import { Component, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
/*import { collection } from 'rxfire/firestore';
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';*/



interface Item{
  name: string,
};



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angularListas';

 item$: Observable<Item[]>;
 constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
  const Collection = collection(firestore, 'items');
  this.item$ = collectionData(Collection);
  }
}
```

archive module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage,getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: sorry for more explain my error is in this part:   ---->  this.item$ = collectionData(Collection);

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the correct type like this:

```
this.item$ = collectionData(Collection) as Observable<Item[]>;
```